# How to control the exit order in Linux command pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, signals

My script:

```
./app 2&>1 | ./pipelog --filename=run.log
```

I use `pipelog` to rotate app's stdout、stderr log.

I tested it, when send SIGTERM to the script during shutdown, two processes receive the signal at the same time:

- the `pipelog` will exit immediately.
- but the `app` has graceful shutdown logic, and it will wait for a while before exiting (the time is uncertain).

The resulting problem is that the last log of the `app` is gone.

How to implement `pipelog` to exit after the `app` exits？

I can only sleep in the `pipelog` for a fixed amount of time now, which is not elegant.

Comment: When you kill a script, there's no way to control the order that the child processes are killed.

Comment: What you'd really like to do is only kill `./app`, and let `pipelog` exit normally when it reads EOF.

Comment: Can you change `app` so its output isn't buffered? Then you shouldn't have to worry about messages that haven't been sent to the log.

Comment: Adding to the idea by Barmar: You can do this withou changing `app` - see _man stdbuf_. In this case, maybe the stdin for `pipelog` should be unbuffered as well, which also goes with help of the `stdbuf` command. All that is left then is writing `run.log` unbuffered. This indeed must be ensured inside `pipelog`, so this is the application you possibly have to change.

Comment: Suggestion: Just use a `systemd` unit, which has proper and unified log management as well as lifecycle tracking for `app`. You could, in theory, figure out the `app`’s PID and send a termination signal (only) to it, after which `pipelog` may exit _after_ `app` exits and the pipe get closed, but … that equals reinventing the wheel. `systemd`’s wheels are more than adequate and known to work.

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek There's no need to add a hard-dep on systemd for something this simple. The thing you say would be possible in theory but reinventing the wheel is in fact the normal and correct way to do this. Remember that too much not reinventing the wheel is why the leftpad incident happened.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Starting random scripts without presence tracking, automated log management, security hardening, dependency resolution etc. etc. is neither _normal_ nor _correct_, it is in fact flawed in each and every possible way. It’s like using a square-shaped “wheel” instead of a universally available round one. A hard dependency on `systemd` is better than a hard dependency on luck and randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will probably work:

```
./app 2&>1 | (trap '' TERM; exec ./pipelog --filename=run.log)
```

With that, `pipelog` should ignore `SIGTERM` and keep running until it gets to `EOF` on its input pipe, which will happen once `app` exits.

I assume `app` and `pipelog` are both in-house programs, so I can't be totally sure this will work, but here's a few failure cases I can think of and what to do about them:

1. If `app` starts daemonized children that share its stdout or stderr, but don't shut down when it does, then they'll keep `pipelog` alive indefinitely. If this is the case, and you can't fix it in `app`, then a solution will probably involve a wrapper program that uses `PR_SET_CHILD_SUBREAPER`.
2. If `pipelog` doesn't exit on EOF, then it will stay alive indefinitely. Any workaround to this would inherently involve a race condition, so if it's the case, you should fix it in `pipelog`'s code.
3. If `pipelog` sets a signal handler for `SIGTERM`, it will override the `trap` above and keep doing what it used to do. If this is the case and you can't disable that, then a solution will probably involve trapping `SIGTERM` in the outer bash script and manually sending it to only `app`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.

Great, I solved my problem based on @Barmar's comment, like you said "ignore SIGTERM and keep running until it gets to EOF".

Comment: I write pipelog use Golang, and ignore SIGTERM in `pipelog` process, so it can be simple like this: `./app 2&>1 | ./pipelog --filename=run.log`.